# Why won't my boto3 filters work for ec2.describe_tags()

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

The request works and returns the correct boto3 response syntax, but it contains tags from resource-type that is 'instance', 'volume' and others. It should only return tags from resource-type of 'volume'. It doesn't successfully only return tags with 'key' of 'Name'.

```
Filters=[
    {
        'Name':'resource-type',
        'Values': [
            'volume',
        ],
        'Name':'key',
        'Values': [
            'Name',
        ],
    },
]

client = boto3.client('ec2', region, aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
tags = client.describe_tags(Filters=Filters)
pprint(tags)
```

Comment: I figured out the answer but Boto3's documentation isn't clear so I thought I would leave the question up and put the answer in the comments to any other wandering poor vagrant souls:

Boto's filters on describe_tags() won't accept multiple filters of different types. You can do as many Name:'key' filters as you want, but resource-type, resource-id and other already named tags you can only choose 1 to filter by.

Comment: Answer the question your self stating I found the solution , so that people can read , many do not read commend but a proper formatted answer will help all.

Thanks